# Is an ATT Call Necessary for Showing Admob Ads?

Tags: admob, ios14, apptrackingtransparency

I have read through several threads relating to this but none could provide a definitive answer.  What I'm specifically wondering is whether an ATT request is necessary for showing a basic Google Admob ad (No mediation, no other networks) in an IOS app.  The reason I ask is because I have read that Admob can only access the IDFA if the IOS user gives their express permission for the specific app.  Therefore, if the ATT pop-up was never presented, the user would never give permission, so Admob would never be able to use it.

I have also read that Google themselves is not showing the ATT request in their apps.  Does this confirm that it is not necessary to present the ATT? Assuming that there is no other data collection or analytics enabled.  Could an expert in the area or someone who has more experience with the IDFA and ATT please give some guidance?  It would be much appreciated

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for reasons listed in the admob tag.

Answer (score 3):

AdMob has two types of ads: personalized and non-personalized. Normal ads are personalized, if you want to show non-personalized ads you must specify this in the request (code made available by Google, you can find it in the documentation for developers)

Apple asks you: Are you trying to access the IDFA? If you are using personalized ads, then you are using IDFA, so you need to update the store app privacy page and show the ATT prompt to users.
If, on the other hand, you are requesting only non-personalized ads, then you do not require the use of the IDFA and it will not be necessary to show the ATT.

Be careful though, because if you tell Apple that you don't want to use the IDFA and therefore don't want to request the ATT, then you won't have access to any IDFA. Access to the IDFA is something that is managed per app, so the only way you can access it is to show the request. Of course in the updates you can change your choice

Therefore:

- Personalized ads, relatively more revenue, IDFA, ATT (leaving the choice to the user, whether to use personalized or non-personalized ads)
- Non-personalized ads, relatively less revenue, you don't have to show any ATT.

---

Small clarification (01/12/2022)
If you ask for personalized ads but the user has denied the ATT, then AdMob should still serve ads, which automatically don't use the IDFA.
Also in a conversation with a Google employee as long as I remember, they told me that IDFA isn't the only customization parameter.

So the specific request for personalized/non-personalized ads via code, do it on the basis of the user's consent to your specific form, such as the consent for the European Union, and not on the basis of the ATT form.

Comment: Hi Francesco, you wrote that "code made available by Google" but can't find it on the Google AdMobs Site (nor via Google Search). Could you post it please :)? Specifically, I check during my App Startup if the user has consent and then want to either request personal or non-personal ads based on it. The consent query via ATT I have implemented, but now I am missing a way to tell AdMob to use either personal or non-personalized ads ... thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, I added a clarification to the answer. As for that code, you can find it on the Google developer site, usually in EU Consent, for example: https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start#forward-consent , https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/eu-consent#forward_consent_to_the_google_mobile_ads_sdk